# Group tags in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a website in Wordpress and am running into a slight problem. My website uses a somewhat complex tagging system in that there are multiple types of tags, such as CLIENTS, COLOR, THEME, and EXTRAS.

By default, all tags live within the same group. Is there any way to organize tags into groups that can later be called by Wordpress? Similar to how the categories work?

Edit: Perhaps there is a way to accomplish this using custom fields? My concern is that custom fields do not work in the same way tags do, in that you can't browse posts that share the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess what you need is [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). With them, you can define independent category structures - so one for clients, one for colors, one for themes and etc.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up using this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a plugin would help you.
Something like [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tag-grouping/) for example?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a plugin called [Tag Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tag-groups/). It should be useful.